# How do I change the save location of my tar ball?

Tags: linux, tar

**Good-day,**

Can someone please tell me how to save my tar ball to another location other than the default directory?  I'm running a tar command as root therefore the archive is being saved in **/root** by default.  I'd like to save the file in an attached hard drive mounted at **/mnt/shares**.  Here's what I've tried so far with the respective responses from the system:

```
tar -C /mnt/shares/flexshares/backup/Server1_HDD -cpzf backup-HDD-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`.tar.gz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/var/flexshare/shares /media

tar --directory=/mnt/shares/flexshares/backup/Server1_HDD -cpzf backup-HDD-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`.tar.gz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/var/flexshare/shares /media
```

The above two attempts both create the archive but still save it in the default directory: **/root**

```
tar /mnt/shares/flexshares/backup/Server1_HDD -cpzf backup-HDD-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`.tar.gz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/var/flexshare/shares /media
```

The above doesn't work and generates this error message:  *tar: invalid option -- /
Try `tar --help' or`tar --usage' for more information.*

I'd like to be able to save the archive directly to **/mnt/shares/flexshares/backup/Server1_HDD**.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

v/r

Kismet

Comment: It said: Try `tar --help`.  You didn't?

Comment: @devnull don't be a RTFM turd; he clearly tried several things before asking his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the full path to the destination.

```
tar ... -cpzf /mnt/shares/flexshares/backup/Server1_HDD/backup-HDD-`date +%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M`.tar.gz ...
```

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize I could specify the full path as part of the archive name.  Thanks, I just learned something.

Comment: It's not an archive name, it's an archive *filename*.

Comment: Not much, except that a filename can include a path.

Answer (score 3):

`-f` gives you control of where you want the file to be output

```
$ tar ... -f /path/to/backup.tar /path/to/file1 /other/file2
```